# Dynamic Case statement in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-10

I am having two arrays. Both array calculated from functions so both arrays are dynamic but length of both arrays will be same.

```
a1= ARRAY[1,2,3];
a2= ARRAY[10,20,30];
```

Now I want to update my table something like this

```
UPDATE TABLE SET data= CASE 
     data=a1[1] then a2[1]
     data=a1[2] then a2[2]
     data=a1[3] then a2[3]END
where id=1;
```

I tried with adding loop inside CASE but it is not working .

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Case _expression_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of  [`array_position`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) to find the matching index in array 1, and query array 2 using this index:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET data = a2[array_position(a1, data)]
WHERE id = 1;
```

http://rextester.com/CBJ37276